# BeautifulSoup - findAll() doesn't return all descendants

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the posts from a forum thread. Everything works fine for most posts, but whenever a post is a reply and it contains the original message, I can't get the reply. I found out that the soup.findAll(...) doesn't return all the children from the html source (see pictures below). From the html in picture 2 I get

```
<b>Citation :</b><br/>
```

where I should also get what's below (in the 'p' tag: si-si je suis là...). Actually I only want the stuff that's in this 'p' tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

site_source = requests.get("http://forum.doctissimo.fr/sante/audition/acouphene-mouvement-secouant-sujet_152572_1.htm").content
soup = bsoup(site_source, "html.parser")

# Get text from forum posts

post_boxes = soup.findAll("td", class_="messCase2", style="border-bottom:0")

for post_box in post_boxes:
    message = post_box.find("div", itemprop="text")
    for line in message:
       print(line)
```

[Picture: new post (the parsing works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaXs1.png)

[Picture: reply post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ6K5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.descendants`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants) to recursively access all the children in a `Tag` object.

There's a bigger problem, though.  The link you provided does not give the same HTML structure as the "reply post" screenshot.  In the actual link, the additional `<p>` tag with the content you want is not part of the `<div>` with `id=77714`.  Here's a screenshot from Chrome's Inspect tab for this page, for the content you're interested in:

[image: HTML source]

That `<div>` appears not to be closed properly, but it is nested within a `<p>` tag, which *is* closed before the next `<div class="container">`.  (This is one good reason not to rely on screenshots when posting a question.)

Your browser may have imputed the dangling `</p>` as `<p></p>`, but `BeautifulSoup` is respecting the apparent tag closure - that's why you don't see your target content in the children set.

Here's what your `<div>` actually contains:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

site_source = requests.get("http://forum.doctissimo.fr/sante/audition/acouphene-mouvement-secouant-sujet_152572_1.htm").content
soup = bsoup(site_source, "html.parser")

div = soup.find_all("div", id="para77714")

for tag in div:
    for subtag in tag.descendants:
        print(subtag)
```

Output:

```
<div itemprop="text"><b>Citation :</b><br/></div>
<b>Citation :</b>
Citation :
<br/>
```

The main problem is that the HTML on this page is a mess.  `BeautifulSoup` quite rightly can't make heads or tails of it.  For example, it *looks* like your target content is wrapped in a `<p>` tag, but because things are all messed up with bad closures earlier on, there isn't actually a valid tag that wraps your content.

You can see this if you iterate down through the tag hierarchy a bit past the starting `<div>`:

```
ct = 0
for tag in div.find_all_next():
    ct+=1
    if (ct < 15) & (ct > 12):
        for subtag in tag:
            print(f"tag name: {subtag.name}")
            print(f"{subtag.string}\n")

tag name: None
Afficher moins

tag name: br
None

tag name: br
None

tag name: br
None

tag name: None
si-si je suis là   <--- this is what you want, but it is not in a valid <p> tag

tag name: img
None
# ...
```

TL;DR - `BeautifulSoup` is working just fine, it's this web page that's busted.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this so I sure am missing some basic stuff about BeautifulSoup. Your explanation is very clear. I guess for my project I'll 'manually' iterate through the hierarchy and check for string objects so I only keep these.

Comment: You're welcome. Malformed HTML is a pain to work with, good luck. If this answer resolved your question, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.